# unable to git clone on remote vm

Tags: git

I am trying to git clone a repository on to my remote vm, and it doesn't work.
I get the following error

```
[PepperBoy@remserver check]$ git clone -b integratedscript https://github.com/PepperBoy/Project101.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/PepperBoy/myscript/Project101/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/PepperBoy/Project101.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

On my personal laptop, when I try the above, it works just fine.

I have tried pinging from the remote vm and it works fine

```
PING github.com (192.30.252.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from github.com (192.30.252.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=85.8 ms
64 bytes from github.com (192.30.252.128): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=86.3 ms
^Z
```

I have also generated an ssh key and added it to my github

```
[PepprBoy@remserver check]$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/PepprBoy/.ssh/id_rsa): y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in y.
Your public key has been saved in y.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
08:f5:25:34:ea:42:c3:fb:7a:67:95:17:a7:83:8a:9e PepprBoy@remserver
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|      ..+ .      |
|   . . o +       |
|    = . .        |
|   . = .    . .  |
|    o o S  o +   |
|     o    + +    |
|      .. o . .   |
|     .o.+        |
|    .oEo         |
+-----------------+
[PepprBoy@remserver check]$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA74n/3lzA2kfu3gnPtwXV4tVbL715Jb6wkTa1IY/OT/p+RXxrg9CVtZThVsz3140bNNk2AsBXAkOAHQq31vBoChO8LNefWQyzK85XWEyJvPHJkwhpgPbZdCZ1xAF/1ItprQxPlhVolZ7zKX1QRKGGkqR5a9uzBpwC9gTC/1bpkcbZYNU3ZRUShqIVvMas58i67M03Z8Z7UrGE0PNCLcw0nMFzediGTXaXHVlKyWBSDvmX96cxO1CvBdIZuzBSVEff6vNZ0orbUQ/9mLCJkrkTBMbSaba6NAA8JZhWrQE3GGdZ7SAHPO+shmH2SPNvv4C+19A+ZWE0h+oawSEYt9e0RQ== PepprBoy@remserver
[PepprBoy@remserver check]$
```

Please let me know how I can git clone this repo to my vm.
(This is actually a private repo)

Comment: the ssh key is unnecessary; you access the repository via HTTPS. Are you sure you're using the right username and password?

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ, It never prompts for me a username or password on the remove vm. On my personal, it does, and when I enter my credentials, it works fine.

Comment: Is that repo a private one?

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ, Yes it's a private repo.

Comment: maybe you've got a very broken git in your VM; try using the SSH URL instead.

Comment: I notice that the OP generated a keypair stored in `y` and `y.pub` and shows that a `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file exists.  But that file isn't important.  It is the `id_rsa` file that is important.  Maybe that file doesn't exit.  If it does, maybe things aren't working because the OP uploaded `y.pub` to GitHub, not `id_rsa.pub`.  I also wonder if the password request that the OP is talking about is in regards to the Git repo, or is it asking for the password to unlock the `id_rsa` file.  TLDR; I'm guessing that the ssh keypair setup on the VM isn't set up right or doesn't match what's on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a `credential-helper` from the running environment, which will cache the password for you. This won't be available to your VM. Where are you putting the password?

Alternatively you may have put the password in your `.netrc` file in the surrounding machine, but not made this available in the VM.